# Lifetime of a Web SQL transaction

Tags: google-chrome, web-sql

What's the lifetime of a Web SQL transaction, or, if it's dynamic, what does it depend on?

From my experience opening a new transaction takes a considerable amount of time, so I was trying to keep the transaction open for the longest time possible.
I also wanted to keep the code clean, so I was trying to separate the JS into abstract functions and passing a transaction as a parameter - something I'm sure is not good practice but sometimes greatly improves performance when it works.

As an example:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    // First question: how many tx.executeSql
    // calls are allowed within one transaction?
    tx.executeSql('[some query]');
    tx.executeSql('[some other query]', [], function (tx, results) {
        // Do something with results
    });

    // Second question: passing the transaction
    // works some times, but not others. Is this
    // allowed by the spec, good practice, and/or
    // limited by any external factors?
    otherFunction(tx, 'some parameter');
});

function otherFunction(tx, param) {
    tx.executeSql('[some query]');
}
```

Also, any suggestions on techniques for speedy access to the Web SQL database would be welcome as well.

Comment: If you're looking for help with your code, please post it. Otherwise this question may be too broad for SO.

Comment: Transaction should reuse as long as as possible for performance. According to spec,  it is not  a problem, but I find too many interlace long transaction cause weird error on safari.it run fine in chrome though.

Comment: Thanks @KyawTun. Chrome gives me an error like `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.` - I was wondering under which conditions this error would come up?